# Joomla - Pulling in articles to an external website through RSS or other method?

Tags: joomla, rss

I have an external website that I want to have pull content from my Joomla website.  Ideally by an RSS feed.

The external website will have a 'thumbnail' that represents the article.

Is it possible to add a custom field to Joomla's New Article page where a user can select a thumbnail from the media library / upload from their computer and send the URL/Path value of the image along with the Article Title and Article Content to the external site through RSS?

Answer (score 1):

If you use K2 you can do that... Each k2 item supports an image that also shows up in RSS feed links!

Also... I think zoo supports that functionality as well!